# Subclass inherited field is never used

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

Can I inherit from a class knowing that some of its fields will never be used?

Let's say I have a Parent class and its subclass Child:

```
public class Parent {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
...
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private String d;
...
}
```

Am I allowed to inherit from a class like that knowing that in my Child class I will only use fields "a", "b", "d" and field "c" will never be used?

P.S. Not asking if compiler is going to complain or not. Asking for a better design practice. If this is bad practice, then how to fix it?

Comment: Define "*allowed*". Will the comiler complain? No. Is it bad design? Yes.

Comment: *Can I inherit a class knowing that some of it's fields will never be used?* - you can inherit from a class even if you won't use any of its fields, you *don't have to* use the supertype fields if you inherit from it. You may inherit from a type to get some behaviour (inherit and/or override methods), or just to mark your class as some particular *type* (implement Serializable, for instance).

Comment: Perhaps the superclass should have getters and maybe setters for the private fields. Also, sometimes you don't need to explicitly use hidden fields to need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. There may or may not be a problem, but focusing on the data contained in the classes is wrong. You must focus on their behavior.

In her keynote address "[Data Abstraction and Hierarchy](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/62138.62141)" Barbara Liskov introduced what is commonly known as the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), expanded on in the paper "[A Behavioral Notion of Subtyping](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/197320.197383)" by Liskov and Jeannette Wing. The idea is that one type is a subtype of another if the subtype could replace the supertype everywhere in a program without impacting its correctness; that is, without breaking it.

What would happen if all `Parent` instances in your program were replaced with `Child` instances? Can the child do everything the parent does? Does it support the same operations? Will it produce the same results?

If the answer to that is yes, then `Child` is a subtype of `Parent`. If the answer to that is no, then it is not and it should not be a subclass of it. Whether field `c` is relevant depends entirely on how it is used.

Comment: if i replace Parent with Child it will work just fine. the thing is that whenever i use class Child there is no need for a "c" field, ever.

Comment: @syd Yes, I understood that from your question. If the behavior doesn't change, then class Child is a subtype of class Parent according to the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: which means that i can inherit from parent class?

Comment: @syd Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

If your Parent class allows being extended and the Child class does not require all the information that its Parent provides, then **it is likely your Parent class does too much and it can be separated into different classes**.

After you made this refactor, you can extend the class that fits better the behavior you want.

Comment: class can not be separated into two, all fields represent its entity. I guess in this case my child class fails "is-a" test because this "c" field is not applicable to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of separating the `Parent` class.

```
class AB {
    Object a;
    Object b;
}
class ABC extends AB {
    Object c;
}
class ABD extends AB {
    Object d;
}
```

Inheritance is a poor tool for code reuse, so you may consider composition instead, if these classes have no shared behavior.

```
class AB {
    Object a;
    Object b;
}
class ABC {
    AB ab;
    Object c;
}
class ABD {
    AB ab;
    Object d;
}
```

Comment: i thought about this as well, but it feels like too much. Basically, with this approach you can create a new child class for every new field there is.

Comment: Presumably that new (unique) field has a new (unique) behavior using it. The idea behind OOP is to encapsulate independent behavior, along with the data it needs, into an Object. In theory that could mean one method and one field per class; but in practice things are unlikely to be so uniform. If it happens that you can cleanly divide your domain into small objects, you're either very lucky or very good at OO design.